# UIImagePickerController with PopOver not working on iPad Device

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the `UIImagePickerController` for picking the image and use the image in ipad application it works fine on simulator but it does not open `imagepickerController` in device here is my code

```
        else if([labelType.text isEqualToString:@"Select Image"]){

        selectedType=@"Select Image";

        BOOL isiPhone;

        UIImagePickerController *pckrImage = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        pckrImage.delegate = self;
        if (isiPhone) {
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) 
            {
                pckrImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;                  
                [self presentModalViewController:pckrImage animated:YES];
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        else
        {
            popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:pckrImage];
            [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(450.0f, 825.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];       
        }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make change as

```
UIImagePickerController *pckrImage = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        pckrImage.delegate = self;
        if (isiPhone) {
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])



            {
                pckrImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;







                [self presentModalViewController:pckrImage animated:YES];
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        else
        {
            UIPopoverController *popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:pckrImage];
            self.popoverImageViewController = popOver;
            [self.popoverImageViewController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(450.0f, 825.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];


        }
```

Initialize the object

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popoverImageViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIImagePickerController *pckrImage = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pckrImage.delegate = self;
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
            pckrImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    if (isiPhone) {

            [self presentModalViewController:pckrImage animated:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:pckrImage];
        [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(450.0f, 825.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];       
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it does not crash on simulator it crashed on devic

Answer (score 0):

Try to present the popover with UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny.

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(450.0f, 825.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f)
                                                            inView:self.view
                                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                          animated:YES];
```